# PushSharp always return device expired

Tags: c#, apns-sharp, pushsharp

I'm trying to send a push notification using https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

I'm using the sample project as is (having commented out the non ios stuff from program.cs), I confirmed that the app i'm using is the correct app, I've regenerated the developer push cert.

I'm running the app from xcode, so that it is devlopment providsioned..

The message seems to go fine, but then comes back

```
Waiting for Queue to Finish...
Sent: Apple -> {"aps":{"alert":"1 Alert Text!","badge":7,"sound":"default"}}
Queue Finished, press return to exit...
Device Subscription Expired: Apple -> [Device Id Removed]
```

I'm getting the device id from my app, to confirm it coumes out broken into Hex Octets, and i simply remove the spaces

So... not sure where to go from here, seems that apns is saying the app doesn't exist on my device, but it certainly does..

Comment: I'm using the sandbox server, and the development provisioning profile on my device.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost always due to a mismatch between the development and production provisioning profile certificates.

Check you're using the correct one... if this is still a problem!